# Wrong owner upon file creation in particular directory

Tags: bash

I'm facing @subj . If I try to create a file/dir in my `home` directory it gets created as `root:daemon` instead of `user:staff`. I found this behaviour only for one directory ( all the other dirs aren't affected).

It used to create files properly before and now it sets `root:daemon` with 644.
I can't see any guid or sticky bits, etc.

What do I miss?

```
$ whoami
user
$ pwd
/home/user
$ touch 1
$ ll 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root daemon 0 Jul 31 09:50 1
$ ls -ld /home/user/
drwxr-xr-x 13 user staff 4096 Jul 31 09:50 /home/user/
$ ls -ld /home/
drwxr-xr-x 5778 root staff 450560 Jul 31 08:21 /home/
$ umask
0022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be due to file access control set to root:daemon. If you run

```
getfacl /home/user
```

it should tell you if that was the problem. If yes, then you can set per-folder with the command `setfacl` with the parameters you prefer.

Another cause that comes to my mind is if that is a mountpoint masked with those particular user and group; you can check that with cat `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: The pity is that on that very server I have no rights to install `getfacl` :-) checked crontab and it is ok. So I suppose that it might be something with acls, but can't proove it. :-)

Comment: can't you even copy a compatible binary of `getfacl` and run it to see if it works? I was thinking about crontab as well, but I thought that if you had touched crontab, then you would have certainly remembered

Comment: On that very machine I'm just an "another employee". I have submitted a ticket to the server administrator. Waiting for his response :)